# How to open this code on a blank page?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know much about coding could you help me with this.
Simply I have a example URL if I input a text, I want add the input to end of example URL and going to link in a blank page

```
<input type="text" id="suffix4" />
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://example.com/sell/123/321/" onclick="document.location.href = $(this).attr('href')+$('#suffix4').val(); return false;">sell it</a>
```

Comment: Your post makes ZERO sense...please re-write and include any relevant code so the community can assist you.

Comment: your code utilizes jQuery. make sure to include a link to jQuery library in the head of your page.

Comment: @racecarjonathan sorry this is first time for me posting a question.I think it is format fair now

Comment: @Banana it is okey.code is working but it is working on current tab of browser,I want it open the link on a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting document.location.href will always load the code in the current page.

Try:

`onclick="window.open($(this).attr('href')+$('#suffix4').val()); return false;"`

Comment: you are missing a closing parenthesis for the open method

Comment: it really worked thank you man.I am so happy with this problem solved :D I'm new to community I dont know how to point out solution found but this is right answer @AndrewEwert

Comment: Glad it worked, you can accept the solution by clicking the check mark to the left (under the up/down arrows). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

scroll down till you see  the target="_blank"